# What is the proper way to store and retrieve string values of PyroGram file_id in mongdb as it is?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, telegram, pyrogram

I have stored `file_id` of files (shared on telegram) into **mongodb** collection. Everything goes fine but the string value of `file_id` becomes invalid if I use from (retrieved the inserted documents) **mongodb**.
But If I simply print the `file_id` on console and copy that string value of `file_id` then it works as I am able to send the file using that id. I wonder that What happens to those string values after getting stored on **mongodb**. I have also tried with text files but still its invalid `file_id`.
so, What is the proper way to store and retrieve string values of **PyroGram** `file_id` in **mongdb** without compromising the string values?

Comment: Perhaps check the encoding of the database. Best to make sure you store values in UTF8 and not another arbitrary encoding to not compromise the strings.

Comment: We would need to see a code snippet showing your issue.